# krpano can't display videos

Tags: video, cloud, frontend, panoramas, krpano

I'm working on a web, which is about panorama.

I try to use a tool named krpano, it can be easily used to display panorama photos and videos. I've tested photos and videos with local ressources.

Now I'm trying to display the ressources stocked in cloud server.

To my surprise, photos can be displayed without any problem, but for videos, I always get such an error:

> ERROR: SecurityError: The video element contains cross-origin data,
>   and may not be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue in krpano

> It's currently not possible to load panoramic video files from other domains because of an iOS / Safari / Webkit bug!

More details here:
https://krpano.com/plugins/videoplayer/#html5.knownbrowserbugs